# HTML5 Custom Elements - using shadow DOM with input element

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to use HTML5 custom elements to create my own form inputs. Right now I have something that looks like:

```
<input-location>
 <!--shadow dom-->
 <input type="text">
 <img src="">
 <button></button>
 <!--/shadow dom-->
</input-location>
```

But I'd prefer it to look something like

```
<input is="input-location">
```

as this would degrade gracefully in older browsers, as well as maintaining functions like .focus/.onfocus etc. However, I am unsure how/where I would place the other elements required by the custom input.

Is this possible? How could I go about it?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: wouldn't you be better using Type and use a poly fill type mechanism to get the behavioud you wish?

Comment: I'm using polymer (polymer-project.org/platform/custom-elements.html) to get the custom elements functionality, so browser support isn't a problem. Using my own input type would hardly be future proof, as something like <input type="location"> seems like it could become part of the HTML5 spec.

Anyway, I'm interested in what the elegant solution would be - if there is one.